# Nativescript directly using android UI elements programmatically

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to programmatically add a android seekbar.

My XML code is:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <StackLayout id="layo" class="home-panel">
        <Label text="Hi" class="h2 description-label" />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

and my JS code is:

```
const application = require("tns-core-modules/application");
var getViewById = require("tns-core-modules/ui/core/view").getViewById;

function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = args.object;

  let context = application.android.context;
  let slid = new android.widget.SeekBar(context);

  getViewById(page, "layo")._addView(slid);
}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

I also tried:

```
getViewById(page, "layo").addChild(slid);
```

But both gives the same error below:

> An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread. Calling js method onCreateView failed
>   Error: android.widget.SeekBar{995277f VFED...........I. 0,0-0,0} is not a valid View instance.

I have very less knowledge on java and I wasn't able to find any solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use nativescript's `placeholder` ([docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder)), see the modified code below for android's seekbar

```html
<StackLayout>
  <Placeholder creatingView="creatingView"/>
</StackLayout>
```

```
import { CreateViewEventData } from "tns-core-modules/ui/placeholder";

export function creatingView(args: CreateViewEventData) {
    let nativeView = new android.widget.SeekBar(args.context);
    args.view = nativeView;
}
```

Comment: I've wanted to note that the above is the straight-forward way for NativeScript Core only (e.g., not applicable in NativeScript Angular). The way to create custom UI components that can be easily reused in different projects (including NativeScript Core, Angular, Vue, React, Svelter, etc.) is to create a plugin. https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins